# Asynchronous Service Operation: No Blocking

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, blocking

I'm trying to have a service operation achieve the following goals:

- Does not allow the thread it is on to block
- "waits" for the input from another service before returning

The first of these two is the capability that [MVC asynchronous controllers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=VS.98%29.aspx) have.  I'm not sure if [WCF iasync operation pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734701.aspx) is equally as clever about allowing the service-dispatch thread to return to the threadpool while it waits for the async operation to complete.

As for the "waiting" for input part, I'm curious if someone has a code sample or even a tiny framework that is designed to have the `EndOperation` invoked when some entirely unrelated event occurs in the system.  If done correctly, the behavior might be equivalent to "long-polling."

Answer (score 0):

Well, use Asynchrone Service-Operation with the Keyword async. It works on .NET 4.5. The Reason of blocks are I/O Operation, which need more time to get the result.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFlightService
{
   [OperationContract]
   cancelFlight();
}

public class FlightService : IFlightService
{
   public async cancelFlight()
   {
      await Task.Delay(5000); 
   }
}
```